# Memcache Symfony2 сессия

Tags: symfony2

Использую MemcacheSessionHandler от Symfony2. Устанавливаю обычное подключение и значение qwerty на странице index.

```
$memcache = new \Memcache();
$memcache->connect('tcp://127.0.0.1','11211');
$storage = new NativeSessionStorage(array(), new Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler($memcache));
$session = new Session($storage);
$session->start();
$session->set('qwerty', 'hehehe');
```

Выбираю сессию на другой странице используя этот код

```
$memcache = new \Memcache();
$memcache->connect('tcp://127.0.0.1','11211');
$storage = new NativeSessionStorage(array(), new Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler($memcache));
$session = new Session($storage);
$session->start();
var_dump($session->get('qwerty'));
```

В ответ получаю NULL, хотя на предыдущей странице сессия была установлена.

Может быть я не так устанавливаю сессию?

Comment: предположу (только предположу!), что сессия не записывается в мемкэш - возможно, ее нужно зарегистрировать внутри симфони для вызова соотыетствующих методов. у вас есть какой-нибудь интерфейс, чтобы определить, записалось что-нибудь в мемкэш, или нет?

Comment: @Etki Видите, в чем суть, я использую ratchet(библиотека для websocket), и по этому на сайте я использую просто отдельно данные библиотеки от симфони2. Т.е я просто прописал namespace и выполняю код, указанный выше. Если использовать не memcache а pdo то на сайте все выставляется, да и на ratchet демоне сессия читается, только apache перекидывает на другой порт и сайт зависает.